# IP/25, can it be begin from xx.xx.xx.128, rather than xx.xx.xx.1?

Tags: networking, server, ip, subnet

I have a dedicated server that I bought from a hosting company. This hosting company assigned me an IP address. However, I needed this dedicated server to use for different VPS servers. I have already split it and now all I need is to assign a valid ip address to each VPS server instead of local ip addresses. So, for example, I want to add 128 more IP addresses to my server.

I expected an IP list, but it resulted with a subnet.

I'm confused because I understand that the hosting company provides me with a subnet. For example, xx.xx.xx.xx/25. (In my contract, the maximum available IP address is limited to 128). I already know that IP is a 32-bit number and /25 is the last bit parts.

I mean, if the range of IP/24 is xx.xx.xx.1-xx.xx.xx.255
and the range of IP/25 is xx.xx.xx.1-xx.xx.xx.127.

Then what happens to the rest of the ip range xx.xx.xx.127-xx.xx.xx.255? I think it will never be used until I give my subnet back to the IP pool.

Or is it possible for someone else to use the rest? Then how should it be displayed, i.e. IP/24-2 or something else?

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains it all.

Comment: `IP/25 is xx.xx.xx.xx.1-xx.xx.xx.xx.127.` no, ip/25 has 2 ranges, one can be assigned to you, another one to somebody else, `Then how should it be displayed` it will be displayed as ip/25, but ip in these two ranges are different by 1 bit

Comment: Dear Ron Maupin, thank you very much for your answer. It was simple link, but a very detailed explanation. I found the answer in the link given in your comment. If you write your comment as an answer, I would like to accept your answer.

Comment: Hello Ilya Bursov,for example if the first IP subnet is xx.xx.xx.0/25 => range xx.xx.xx.0 - xx.xx.xx.127. second one is what? Is that shown as xx.xx.xx.128/25? i.e. range xx.xx.xx.128-xx.xx.xx.255? 0 in 8bit is 00000000 and 128 in 8bit is 10000000. AND /25 means, last 7bit is under assigned IP subnet, hence 25.bit is changed and displayed as xx.xx.xx.128/something new maybe 27,28, etc.

Comment: @onuryildiz right, `x.x.x.0/25` and `x.x.x.128/25` are two subnets, first defines 0-127 range, second 128-255, the differ by single most left bit in 4th octet

Answer (score 0):

The address range for /24 is `w.x.y.0` to `w.x.y.255`.

The address range for /25 is either `w.x.y.0..127` or `w.x.y.128..255`.

A common notation is e.g. `192.168.0.129/25` for the first usable address in `192.168.0.128/25`.

In an IPv4 subnet, the first (all host-part bits zero) and the last address (all host-part bits one) aren't usable for hosts. The former is by convention and the latter is the subnet's directed broadcast address.